# How to change a global variable dependent of other global variables inside the Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables, local-variables

My task is to implement Euler's method in Python with five arguments and one of them is a function f dependent on variables t and x (precisely: f(t,x)). When I tried to execute Euler's method with a given function f, I got errors, because I did not declare variables t and x.
I declared them as equal to 1 (it could have been any other value) and decided to change their values inside the function. Unfortunately, after changing values, I still get a result for x=t=1 (I checked it by using **print(f)**. I tried to use **global**, but it looks like function f is still dependent on x=1 and t=1.
How do I change values of t and x inside "Euler" function? Or maybe there is more efficient way to complete the task?

```
from math import sin,cos

def Euler(f,x_0,t_0,T,n):
    h=(T-t_0)/n
    x_list=[x_0]
    t_list=[t_0]
    for i in range(n):
        global x
        x=x_list[i]
        global t
        t=t_list[i]
        next_x=x+h*f
        x_list.append(next_x)
        next_t=round(t+h, 2)
        t_list.append(next_t)
    return t_list,x_list

x=1
t=1

sol=Euler((-2)*(x-cos(t))-sin(t),1,0,2,20)

print(sol)
```

Comment: The function doesn't use the global `x` and `t` because it reassigns them with ` x = x_list[i]` and `t = t_list[i]`. They're only used to calculate `x_0` and `t_0` in the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it seems that there's a misunderstanding on how to pass a function as an argument in Python. When you call the `Euler` function with `(-2)*(x-cos(t))-sin(t)` as the first argument, Python immediately tries to evaluate this expression using the current values of `x` and `t`, which are both 1. This results in a number, not a function.

To correctly pass a function that depends on `t` and `x`, you should define a separate function, and then pass this function to your `Euler` function.

The use of global variables `t` and `x` inside the `Euler` function is unnecessary and can lead to confusion. Instead, the values for `t` and `x` should be obtained from the `t_list` and `x_list` variables, respectively, and passed to the function `f`.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```py
from math import sin, cos

def Euler(f, x_0, t_0, T, n):
    h = (T - t_0) / n
    x_list = [x_0]
    t_list = [t_0]
    for i in range(n):
        x = x_list[i]
        t = t_list[i]
        next_x = x + h * f(t, x)
        x_list.append(next_x)
        next_t = round(t + h, 2)
        t_list.append(next_t)
    return t_list, x_list

# Defining the function to pass to Euler's method
def my_func(t, x):
    return -2 * (x - cos(t)) - sin(t)

sol = Euler(my_func, 1, 0, 2, 20)

print(sol)
```

In this updated version, `my_func` is defined as a function of `t` and `x`, and this function is passed to `Euler`. Inside the `Euler` function, `my_func` (or more generally `f`) is called with the appropriate arguments `t` and `x`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand my mistake now. But now, let's assume that I would like to change function f to a different formula. Do I always have to change the return of `my_func` to do so? Is there any type allowing me to write, for example, `sin(x)+cos(t)` as an argument `f`?

Comment: @Karol Wyrębkiewicz alternatively you could use either  an anonymous function `Euler(lambda t, x: -2 * (x - cos(t)) - sin(t), ...)` or a string evaluation with `eval` / `ast.literal_eval`, `Euler(eval("-2 * (x - cos(t)) - sin(t)"), ...)`

Comment: In Python, you can use lambda functions to define f directly in the function call, like this: sol = Euler(lambda t, x: sin(x) + cos(t), 1, 0, 2, 20). This allows you to vary f without defining a new function each time.